# Difference between cpanel port numbers 2082 and 2083

Tags: port, cpanel, web-hosting

Can anyone explain about the difference between two port numbers of cpanel 2082 and 2083 ? Simply I mean 2083 is hyper text transfer protocol secure and other is not ?

Comment: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AccessingServices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Found answer to my question.

```
cPanel port number 2082
```

It is the way of establishing an unencrypted connection to the server through **http**(hyper text transfer protocol) opens a connection to the **port number 80**

```
cPanel port number 2083
```

It is the way of establishing an encrypted connection to the server through a secure socket layer through **https** (hyper text transfer protocol secure) opens a connection to the **port number 443**